# Let $f: G\to G'$ be a group homomorphism. There is a bijection from the $\ker(f)$ to the preimage of $h$ in the image $f (f^{-1}(h))$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is difficult to wrap my head around.  If I am reading this right, there is a bijection from (elements in G that map to the neutral element in G') to (any element g in G whose image is h in G'.)  How can I show this or at least conceptualize it better?

Comment: What did they say $h $ was in this instance? Just some arbitrary element?

Comment: You could try an easy case to start understanding it, like when $f$ is an isomorphism. In the case the kernel is just the identity of $G$, , and every element of $G'$ has exactly one preimage, so there has to be a bijection.

Comment: It's worded absolutely horribly. Since $f\big(f^{-1}(h)\big) = \{h\}$ essentially by definition, it would be equivalent to "There is a bijection from $\ker f$ to the preimage $f^{-1}(h)$ of $h$" (presumably it's understood that $h$ can be any group element). Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments section, this is poorly worded.

What it is really asking for is a bijection between elements of the set $\text{ker}(f)=\{x\in G|f(x)=e'\}$ (where $e'$ is the identity in $G'$) and the set $f^{-1}(h)=\{y\in G|f(y)=h\}$ for some $h\in G'$.

Note - you actually need to specify $h\in \text{im}(f)$, or else $f^{-1}(h)$ might be the empty set, while the kernel must at least contain the identity element of $G$. Then you could never find a bijection!

Hopefully you can see how similar these sets are already!

The key is to find a way to move between these two sets - elements mapped to the identity, and elements mapped to $h$. Remember that we're dealing with a homomorphism here, so $f$ will respect all the operations of composition; does this suggest a way to send an element mapped to $h$ under $f$ to a corresponding element mapped to the identity?

Hint:

> Use the inverse of $h$!

Comment: Good catch about the empty set! That's probably the source of the clunky wording, but I'm still a little puzzled about the need to mention $f(f^{-1}(h))$.

Comment: Perhaps they were trying to communicate the fact that $h$ really was in the image of $f$? I.e, "There exists some h in the image of $f^{-1}(h)$? 
Hard to imagine what else they might have been trying to speak to!